# Use multiple variables in "if" statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I have some variables like this:

```
$elm = $_GET['elm']; 
$elm_nm = $_GET['elm_nm']; 
$tag = $_GET['tag'];
```

And some PHP code like this:

```
if (!empty($elm)) {

foreach($html->find($elm, $elm_nm) as $d) {
 echo $d->outertext;
}  

} else { 

echo "noop";

}
```

I would like to have more than one var in the if statement so I tried:

```
if (!empty($elm, $elm_nm, $tag)) {
```

And

```
if (!empty($elm . $elm_nm . $tag)) {
```

And some other things but Dreamweaver is giving me errors on this line. How do I write this properly?

Comment: What do you want to say ? Only run when all of elm elm_num and tag are empty ?

Comment: `if ($statement1 && $statement2 && ....)` D'u even read mans?

Comment: @ u_mulder Still giving me errors...What does "D'u even read mans" mean..?

Comment: d'u even read mans => Do you even read manuals

Comment: @DKSan Thank you:) Sometimes, not when Im on a deadline..Then I just Google and finally ask on Stack

Comment: Minus 1, care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check for all your parameters.

```
$something_is_empty = false;   // set our flag to false

foreach($_GET as $a_parameter) // this will create a loop for every element in GET array
{                              // and the variable $a_parameter will get the value of one GET element each time.
                               // this way we will scan every element of GET array

   if(isempty($a_parameter))   // if something is empty, raise the flag
       $something_is_empty=true; 
}

if($something_is_empty) // if flag is raised, something was empty
{
    echo "noop";
}
else // if flag was not raised, EVERY element in GET array WAS NOT EMPTY
{
    echo "everything has a value!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if ( !empty($elm) &&  !empty($elm_nm) &&  !empty($tag) ) {..}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine this with &&

Like this:

```
if (!empty($elm) && !empty($elm_nm) && !empty($tag)) {
```